# My texture bake of my model seems to not render the textures on the correct polys on the UV map

Tags: modeling, texturing, uv

[image]

I do have 15 different materials on the model but baking worked fine on the other model i did
here is the blend file if needed, i really cant figure this out on my own and ive been trying for hours 
https://drive.google.com/open?id=1W3HREcwcD7pMTBYW8_dHmZswikf0zzPt

Answer (score 0):

I just did some digging around in the nodes and the issue seemed to be something with the image texture node, so i just deleted all those nodes on all my materials and that fixed it.